# How create DDL of missing functions after comparing with another schema in oracle?

Tags: oracle, ddl

I want to import functions/procedures from another database only those that are not exist in my current database.
I got object name using this:-

```
select OBJECT_NAME from dba_objects where owner = 'AKHSYS'  and  object_type in ( 'PROCEDURE', 'PACKAGE', 'FUNCTION', 'PACKAGE BODY' ) minus select OBJECT_NAME from dba_objects  where owner = 'LDHSYS'  and object_type in ( 'PROCEDURE', 'PACKAGE', 'FUNCTION', 'PACKAGE BODY' );
```

but how can I create ddl script of all functions that are missing in my current schema?

Answer (score 1):

Use [DBMS_METADATA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_metada.htm#i1019414). Example:

```
SELECT owner, object_type, object_name, DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl (object_type, object_name, owner)
  FROM (SELECT owner, OBJECT_NAME, object_type
          FROM dba_objects
         WHERE owner = USER AND object_type IN ('PROCEDURE', 'PACKAGE', 'FUNCTION'))
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```